# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null(…) (no matter what I do)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been working on a basic pong game using javascript, html and css for coding experience.

I've searched, researched, and debugged my code all night, and I'm stumped. I found out through console logs that I could access the child object of div by id, but I couldn't access the same element through it's parent object using parent.children/parent.children[0]/parent.childrenCount or anything.

My code areas of interest are lines 12-21 in the .html file, 12 and 58 in the .js file. Like I mentioned, I can access the element object through getElementById, but I can't access it through it's parent's object.children property.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Stupid Pong</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stupid Pong.css">
    <script src="Stupid Pong.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="GameAssets">
    <div id="CanvasFrame">

    <h1 id="Title">Stupid Pong</h1>
    <div id="Popup">
        <div id="PopupMessage">
            Winning score
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="getText">
        <button onclick="Ok()">Set</button>
        <button onclick="Ok()">Play</button>
        <button onclick="Ok()">Controls</button>
        <button onclick="Ok()">Settings</button>
    </div>
    <canvas id="Game_Feild" width="640" height="480">
        This browser isn't hip enough to render Stupid Pong.
    </canvas>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
// Canvas Variables
var GameCanvas;
var CanvasFrame;
var DrawKit;

// Game settings
var WinningScore;
var Difficulty;
var FPS;

// Input
var Popup = {
    pframe: document.getElementById('Popup'),
    messageBox: document.getElementById('PopupMessage')
};/*
var Button = [
    document.getElementById('Popup').children[2],
    document.getElementById('Popup').children[3],
    document.getElementById('Popup').children[4],
    document.getElementById('Popup').children[5]
];
*/


// New Ball
function createBall(x, y, r){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
    this.draw = function(){
        DrawKit.fillStyle = 'white';
        DrawKit.beginPath();
        DrawKit.arc(ballX, ballY, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        DrawKit.fill();
    }
}

// New Paddle
function createPaddle(x, y, width, height){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.draw = function(){
        DrawKit.fillStyle = white;
        DrawKit.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
}


// Load Canvas
window.onload = function(){
    // Canvas Assets
    GameCanvas = document.getElementById('Game_Feild');
    CanvasFrame = document.getElementById('CanvasFrame');
    DrawKit = GameCanvas.getContext('2d');

    console.log(typeof Popup);
    console.log(typeof Popup.pframe);
    console.log(typeof Popup.messageBox);
    console.log(typeof Popup.pframe.children);
    // ...
    for(var i = 3; i < 6; i++){
        //console.log(typeof Popup.children[i]);
        //Button[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
}
// Manual Settings
/*
var SetWinningScore = function{
    var entry = Popup.messageBox.children[1].value
    Button[0].Ok = function{
        if(typeof entry == 'number'){

        }
        else{
            Popup.messageBox.children[0].value = "The \"winning score\" variable is" +
            "a number. In other words, how many points 
        }
    }
}*/
```

Comment: That's more code than I have time to properly analyse right now, but try moving the `<script>` element to the end of the body just before the closing `</body>` tag. Currently you are setting up your `Popup` object to try to reference DOM elements that have not yet been parsed, so `Popup.messageBox` will be `null` because `document.getElementById()` couldn't find the element. (Or you could move that code into your `window.onload` handler.)

Comment: In your `html` div `<div id="PopupMessage">` does not have any child, So how do you expect that `var entry = Popup.messageBox.children[1].value` does not throw error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think the line `var Popup = { ... }` is being evaluated before the DOM is done rendering. So at that time, there are no children and that's the state you're stuck with.

Put the `window.onload = function () { ... }` around the entire JS file. Or do what [nnnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn) suggests in the above comment and move the `script` tag to the bottom of the body. Either way will ensure that the DOM is fully available when the variables dependent on DOM elements are assigned.

Comment: Thanks a million. I decided to set the object properties inside the onload function and it worked like a charm.